# How many unique observations will appear when sampling subsequences from a sequence?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, sampling

I have an ordered sequence of observations

$$X = \{x_1, x_2, x_3, ..., x_n\}$$

and I am sampling subsequences of length $T$ from $X$. A subsequence would look like

$$S = \{x_i, x_{i+1}, ..., x_{i+T}\}$$

with $T<n$ and $\text{max}(i) < n-T$. Each subsequence is sampled **with replacement**.

If I sample $m$ subsequences (with replacement) of length $T$ from $X$, how many unique observations $x_i$ can I expect to get?

Perhaps another way to frame the question is, how many times $m$ do I have to sample subsequences from $X$ to get a minimum threshold $K$ of unique observations, where $K$ is a percentage of the total number of observations in $X$.

Comment: The subsequence $S$ is of length $T+1$, not $T$. Why is $i = n-T$ not allowed? And I don't see how the question in the last paragraph is another way to frame the same question – it seems like an entirely different question to me.

Comment: Sorry, maybe I should have said $max(i)\leq n-T$, not strictly less than. This is so the subsequence $S$ is always of length $T$ (or $T-1$ as you pointed out), so that you can't sample $j$ steps from the end of $X$ where $j<T$. As for the last question, I appreciate it is different, but knowing the answer to either would help me understand the problem better.

Comment: If I understand the question correctly, the first part of quest is not that difficult. Assume each subsequence is equally likely to be sampled, and with replacement we presume that they are independent. Then you can compute the probability that a particular observation does not appear / appear at least once in $m$ sample, with the observation in the middle pack has a larger probability to appear. The number of observations appeared at least once is the sum of indicators of each observations. Then solve by using linearity of expectation.